# How to determine the irreducible representations of a product of Clifford algebra generators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, representation-theory, fermions, oscillators, clifford-algebra

Suppose $\psi^a$, $\psi_{a}$ ($a=1,2,3,4$) are lowering and raising spinorial oscillators, respectively, and generate a Clifford algebra $\{\psi^a, \psi_{b} \} = \delta^a_b$, where an upper $a$ index represents a $\bf 4$ of $\mathfrak{su}(\bf 4)$ and a lower $a$ index represents a $\bf \bar{4}$ of $\mathfrak{su}(\bf 4)$. Also, $\psi^a\psi^a= \psi_a \psi_a= \psi^a |0> = 0$ (no sum over $a$). How do I determine how products of the oscillators $\psi^a$ and $\psi_a$ acting on the vacuum, like $\psi_a \psi_b |0>$ and $\psi_a \psi_b \psi_c |0>$, transform under irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{su}(\bf 4)$?

PS:I think this could be determined using young tableaux but I can't figure out how. I only know how to use young tableaux for a tensor product of two terms and without the terms being the generators of a Clifford algebra.

Comment: $\psi_a \psi_b \left | 0 \right >$ will transform reducibly and its irreducible components will be the RHS of $\textbf{4} \times \textbf{4}$.

Comment: @ConnorBehan What do you mean by RHS $\bf 4 \times \bf 4$?

Comment: I mean the tensor product... a finite sum of irreps whose dimensions add up to 16.